# Executing powershell script file which is a string value

Tags: powershell

I have script file Get-ProcesWithParam.ps1 as

```
 param(
 $name
 )

 function List-Process($name)
 {
    Write-Host "Process List"
    get-process -name $name
    #get-process

}

List-Process -name $name
```

In another script I get this file name as string variable

```
$scriptFile = Get-ExecFile # returns "C:\Get-ProcesWithParam.ps1"
#execute the script
# ... other code ...
```

problem is i need to execute this file (pass the argument to file as well!)

I tried Invoke-Command

```
 invoke-command -scriptblock { param($name) $scriptFile -name $name } -ArgumentList "chrome"
```

but it did not work, it just prints the file name how can i execute the file which is there in the string variable $stringFile ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `&`:

```
$foo = ".\Get-ProcesWithParam.ps1"
$bar="iexplore"
& $foo $bar
```

Comment: In the case of using a switch as a param, I got it working by running 

```& $foo -myswitch
```