# Calling a cmdlet via a value

Tags: c#, function, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a variable in my psm1 file that's a KVP hash

```
$subcmdlist = @{
"addhost" = "Add-Host";
"deletehost" = "Remove-Host";
"setparameter" = "Set-Parameter";
}
```

This psm1 file also has a function called 'newtask' which accepts an argument of $subcommand.

I'm wondering how i can execute the cmdlet Add-Host when

> newtask addhost

is issued from the shell.

I tried to just echo it but that didn't do much good at all. Just printed out the value.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Powershell, how do you execute an arbitrary native command from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/in-powershell-how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149167/executing-powershell-script-file-which-is-a-string-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&` sign (aka the call operator), like this: `& "Get-Host"`. This works at least in Powershell 3.0.

Comment: I just realized that calling Invoke-Expression may be better suited for this. See here: http://ss64.com/ps/call.html and here: http://ss64.com/ps/invoke-expression.html